# Set program as default for all openable files on mac

Tags: macos, mac, applications, file

Is there a way to set a program as default, for all file types it can open? I know there is a setting for this in windows, but how can I do this on Mac? Or at least a menu where I can toggle all files that can be opened, like you can in windows?

**1. Set as default**
**2. List of files**
[image: none][image: none]

Comment: Thanks. Using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), works like a charm

Comment: Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0):

For those who may ask the question in the future, [this thread](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CF4QFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F92294%2Fhow-to-make-a-particular-app-the-default-viewer-editor-for-all-its-supported-f&ei=ILRrVazqBoG2sQXPqIDQDg&usg=AFQjCNHs5I43eTn2sgzGjgvuHz_6PojMgQ&sig2=PftCT6MMVl6H7LsrVQxSqA&bvm=bv.94455598,d.b2w) has instructions.

- Edit plist
- Use an app such as [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)

Cheers!